# Delete action doesn't work for entities without dependencies in entity framework

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Here is my Delete action code and when I try to delete an entity which doesn't contain any dependencies. It always return index without delete. I just want to set it only for the entities with dependencies and others should allow deleted and add to the log.

```
    // GET: Company/5/Delete
        [Route("{companyPk:int}/Delete")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? companyPk)
        {
            //Validate parameters
            if (companyPk == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Company identifier is missing.");
            }

            //Get the model from db
            Company company = await _work.Companies.GetAsync(companyPk);
            if (company == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            //Convert model to dto
            CompanyDto companyDto = _mapper.Map<CompanyDto>(company);

            return View(companyDto);
        }

        // POST: Company/5/Delete
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Route("{companyPk:int}/Delete")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int companyPk)
        {
            //Get the model from db
            Company company = await _work.Companies.GetAsync(companyPk);

            var Related = _work.Companies.Where(i => i.CompanyPk == companyPk)
                .Include(i => i.Departments)
                .Include(i => i.Locations);
                //.FirstOrDefault();

            if (Related != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = String.Format("Company Pk has dependencies for Department and Location. Can't Delete");
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            //Prepare log model
            var logCompany = _mapper.Map<LogCompany>(company);
                logCompany.RecordId = 0;
                Utilities.Instance.SetLogEntityProperties(logCompany, "D");

                //Save model to db
                _work.LogCompanies.Add(logCompany);
                _work.Companies.Remove(company);
                await _work.CompleteAsync();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Why do you expect Related to be null?  And why did you comment out the line with FirstOrDefault that should materialize the query?

Comment: I wanted to delete entities without any foriegn key dependencies and thats why I expect related to be null.Sorry, I was mistakenly Commented FirstOrDefault.  Now I uncomment the FirstOrDefault, but It doesn't make any change. @Steve

Comment: Because the Company exists. Did you check if the Included properties are null?

Comment: Yes I checked. I have 2 companies. Company Pk = 001 and 002. Company Pk 001 has dependencies in department and location. Company Pk 002 doesn't have any dependency in department or location. But I can't delete Company Pk 002.@Steve

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this line after the delete one?

```
_work.SaveChanges();
```

As far as i know, without it, you just delete locally, and savechanges edit into the DB as well.

Comment: Yes I tried. But it doesn't work. when I removw the dependency checking part this previous code worked. May be the issue is with that part. But I can't find it. @StefanaB

Comment: I think maybe Related  always return an instanted object, but if there are no related info, it is an created, empty object (not null but with no content), so it is always triggered. It can help to check in that if the lenght of _work.Companies. It is an list containing all the items, so if there are no companies related, the list length should be 0.

Comment: So how can I do this? Can you please explain me.@StefanaB

Comment: Foreign key (in your case _work.Companies) is a collection. You can see it's count: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.collection-1.count?view=netframework-4.8 . Something like _work.Companies.Count . If the list is empty, it will return 0